# Creating SQL queries with pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

[image]

Actually there is no csv file. I have parquet files. In that I need to extract data from three tables. The tables are publication,section and alt section tables
As you can see from the images, I need the following outputs

I have a dataframe like this as shown in the screenshot.

I need to get the following output as a dataframe

```
pub number std kw1   stdkw2
---------------------------    
1078143      T.       Art.
```

Like this if there are 3 or more values for the same number it should take all of them as stdkw1,stdkw2,stdkw3 etc..

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the dataframe by pub_number. Then iterate over the groups. Append the std_section_name values with pub_number to the result list. Create a dataframe with data from the result list. Later add column names to the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3333,1078143,'T.'],[3333,1078143,'ssss'],[3334,1078145,'Art'],[3334,1078145,'Art'],[3334,1078145,'Art'],[3334,1078145,'Art'],[3334,1078143,'team']],columns=['section_id','pub_number','std_section_name'])
result = list()
for name,group in  df.groupby(by = ['pub_number']):
    if group.shape[0] < 3:
        continue
    result.append([name] + group['std_section_name'].tolist())
ref = pd.DataFrame(result)
ref.columns = ["pub_number"] + ["stdkw" + str(i) for i in range(1,ref.shape[1])]
print(ref)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236622/discussion-on-answer-by-theunknownsai-creating-sql-queries-with-pandas-dataframe).